# Questions about Batch Messaging

Tags: php, email, batch-file, mailgun

According to the documentation I can send 1000 email addresses to the Mailgun API, but since my Mailgun account is new I can only send 100 emails an hour.

I am using Mailgun PHP SDK (version 2.3).

Two questions:

1) Even though I can only send 100 emails an hour, can I send as many messages to the Mailgun API and it will queue them, and each hour it will send 100 emails hour until they are all sent?

2) Documentation says:

> The benefit of using this class is that the recipients tally is monitored and will automatically submit the message to the endpoint when you've added the 1,000th recipient.

Does this mean I can add 1,600 addresses, it will send on the 1,000th and keep going? I assume not since I would need to call `finalize()`, so I find the wording a bit weird.

Is the following the best way to handle sending 1,600 emails?

1. Get complete list of users the email gets sent to (lets say 1600).
2. Take 1,000 of those users and send the email to Mailgun.
3. Remove the previous users and send the remaining 600 to Mailgun.

Here's the code for the above flow:

```
$database->query('SELECT `username`, `email` FROM `users`');
$count = $database->count();

$body = "Hello %recipient.username%,<br><br>$message";

$mgClient = new Mailgun(MAIL_API_KEY);
$domain = MAIL_DOMAIN;

$i = 0;
$batch = 1000;

# Create an empty array to hold the users.
$toUsers = [];

foreach ($database->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $index => $receiver) {
    # Increment the email counter by one.
    $i++;

    # Add user to array.
    $toUsers += array(
        $receiver->email => array(
            'username' => $receiver->username
        )
    );

    # Check if the current number of emails sent equals (or is greater than) the batch number or,
    #   If the number of recipients equals the array index we are currently on.
    if (($i >= $batch) || ($count == $index + 1)) {

        # Make the call to the client.
        $msg = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
            'from' => MAIL_USER,
            'to' => implode(', ', array_keys($toUsers)),
            'subject' => $subject,
            'html' => $body,
            'recipient-variables' => json_encode($toUsers)
        ));

        # Anything other then a code of 200 is an error, so throw an exception.
        if ($msg->http_response_code != 200) {
            throw new Exception('Message could not be sent.');
        }

        # Reset the users array.
        $toUsers = [];

        # Reset the increment.
        $i = 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I said screw it and sent the emails. Result: It sent the first 1000 emails, but "disabled" my Mailgun account for about 12 hours. After it was enabled again, it sent the rest of the emails and disabled my account again but this time not for as long. I assume it calculates how long to disable it for on how many emails over the 100/hour limit you sent.